# Why isn't Busy Beaver Infinite for n < trivial k?

Tags: complexity-theory

I am clearly not understanding the Busy Beaver function. Why wouldn't it be infinite for n > k, 
while(true)
{
  print("1");
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Busy Beaver function considers only terminating TMs, that is only those that execute for some finite number of steps.